# Loop integrals in particle physics: Odd number of momenta and tensor decomposition

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, feynman-diagrams, integration, dimensional-regularization

Given the following two-loop tensor integral,

$$
    \int \frac{\text{d}^D k_1}{(2\pi)^D} \int \frac{\text{d}^D k_2}{(2\pi)^D} \frac{k_1^\mu k_1^\nu k_2^\rho}{(k_1^2-a)^\alpha (k_2^2-b)^\beta ((k_1 + k_2)^2-c)^\gamma} $$

the first step is to reduce it to scalar integrals. In some advanced lectures and articles, this is called *tensor integral decomposition*. But in some textbooks this is treated superficially. For example, in *Weinberg, The Quantum Theory Of Fields*:

> [...] the most conveninent method for regulating divergent integrals [...] amounts to carrying out angular averages in integrals like (11.2.7) by dropping all terms that are odd in [powers of loop momentum] and replacing the terms that have even numbers [of loop momenta] with
> $$k^a k^b \to g^{ab} \frac{k^2}{D} $$

- Odd number of loop momenta:

I don't see how my integral above (with odd number of k in the numerator) could be zero, as the denominator is not even in $k_{1,2}$ due to the crossed term, $(k_1 + k_2)^2 = 2 k_1\cdot k_2 +...$.

- Tensor decomposition: Is there an analogous formula to substitute the product of three loop momenta?

$$k_1^a k_1^b k_2^c \to ?$$

Any comment would be very helpful. Thank you.

**Comments**

- From other references, I understood that the substitution of the Weinberg does not apply if there are external momenta inside the integral. In tensor integral decompostion, one has to construct all tensor structures, with the same rank as the origianl integral, using the metric tensor and external momenta (if any). But in this case, since there is no external momentum in the denominator, I cannot imagine a structure with three indices, only using the metric tensor.
- The feyncalc function `Tdec` and `FCMultiLoopTID` yield directly

$$k_1^a k_2^b k_1^c \to 0$$

Comment: If you change integration constants to $k_1,k_2 \to -k_1,-k_2$, then you can prove that $I=-I \implies I = 0$.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the comment. I only tried to change the sign of $k_2$. But if there were external momenta in the denominator, _e.g._ $((k_2-p)^2 - b)^\beta$, would it also vanish (I cannot find the needed momentum shift) . In other words, integrals with odd number of loop momenta in the numerator always vanish?

Comment: it is not true that integrals with odd number of momenta in numerator vanishes always. The structure of the denominator has to be of a special form for that to be true.